# Redirect с backend'а на frontend nodejs/react

Tags: express

Разрабатываем приложение с фронтом на React и бэком на Node (Express). В приложении реализована авторизация пользователя с последующей отправкой по email ссылки для активации. По задумке, пользователь после активации (перехода по ссылке) должен попасть на главную страницу приложения.
Все отлично работало в режиме development, когда обе части приложения реально находились на одном компе. А в режиме production ничего не работает. Раньше при переходе по ссылке на бэк делался запрос из письма, запрос принимался на бэке, обрабатывался и в конце делался
`return res.redirect('localhost:4200/emailConfirm');`
Сейчас вопрос в том, где мне взять URL или HOST клиента для правильного redirect'а?

Comment: У вас сервер сейчас по какому имени отвечает? Вот такое и подставьте. Либо можно выдернуть из req.hostname к примеру

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. У меня сервер имеет URL www.some_hosting.ru:3333, а фронт www.some_hosting.ru. Я в redirect указаываю URL 'emailConfirm', в браззере в адресной строке адрес появляется www.some_hosting.ru:3333/emailConfirm, а надо www.some_hosting.ru/emailConfirm. Для опытного бэкендера наверное задача очень простая, но я к сожалению начинающий, вот и пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Ну так в выдаваемой ссылке пользователю уберите порт(3333)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Поменял статус 302 на 301, и пошло дело